# Can't change screen brightness on ubuntu 20.04 (Always display maximum brightness)

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, asus, brightness

I'm new to linux and this is my first installation of ubuntu 20.04 on ASUS ROG ZEPHYRUS G14 laptop. After installation, I can't change the screen brightness and my screen always show the highest screen brightness. After some time of changing grub in ubuntu forum, this is my attempts

1. Add `acpi_brightness=vendor` or `acpi_backlight=native` or `acpi_backlight=native` or `acpi_backlight=none` to grub `etc/default/grub` still not working
2. After that I installed **brightness-controller-simple** and **brightness-controller** and slide the brightness control to minimum and my screen brightness stays the same
3. I installed **xbacklight** and run this command `xbacklight -set 50` still didn't work

Note : I manged to install nvidia drivers on my laptop after using nouveau for 2 days
and this is my result after run this command `ls /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` >>> `actual_brightness  brightness  max_brightness  scale      type bl_power           device      power           subsystem  uevent`

My laptop specs : CPU : AMD Ryzen 7 4800HS
GPU : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti 4GB GDDR6
RAM : 16 GB
Kernel : Linux 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5`? (If it dulls your screen too much, reset it with `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 1`. This isn't really a solution, I just want to see if it dims and we can go from there (maybe). If you're curious, each `0.1` is equal to 10% brightness, so 0.0 = 0% and 1 = 100%. LVDS1 is standard laptop display, but there's also DVI1 (and DVI2), HDMI1, DP1, and VGA1.

Comment: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output LVDS1 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.`

Comment: I got this error after run ```xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 1 or 0.5 xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output LVDS1 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same laptop, same situation. Finally found the solution to be an upgrade to a new linux kernel.

Ubuntu 20.04 came with 5.4.x, Installing 5.7.15 fixed it for me. The hotkeys for brightness control still didn't work with fn but I mapped the  f7 and f8 to that as I don't use them often.

Don't try to compile linux kernels yourself if you're not sure how that works, just use [mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline). You might have to disable secureboot from the bios for some of the kernel versions. I had to disable it for 5.7.15

A comprehensive discussion for some other problems with this setup can be found at [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/hbqa7r/issues_ryzen_4000_4800u_compatibility_ubuntu_2004/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share)

Comment: I have the same laptop and upgrading linux kernel fixed the problem for me. Instruction for upgrading linux kernel can be found here: https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/, More over I install the brightness-controller.

Comment: I have  a Lenovo X1 Yoga and updating the kernel did not fix it.